# Flash : Creating object at point

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

can someone please tell me how to create a new object on point ?
I wish to do something like this :
`addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

```
    private function loop(e:Event):void

        addChild {(myObject)} on(mouseX,mouseY);
        }`
```

I know it is bad code, but i wanted just show you what i want to do, so please help me :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
private function loop(e:Event):void{
    addChild(myObject);
    myObject.x = mouseX;
    myObject.y = mouseY;
}
```